# Python alternative to Adobe Real Time Messaging Protocol

Tags: python, streaming, video-streaming, audio-streaming

Is there a way to stream audio and video over the internet using Python Web Programming and not Flash?

Answer (score 0):

Python is a server-side language, Flash is a client-side language. They do completely different things.

If you want to look at video streaming that doesn't require Flash, take a look at the [HTML5 video element](http://www.html5video.org/), which is a portion of the HTML5 standard being developed and is handled client-side by the browser.

Comment: I meant can Python replicate the functionality of the Flash Server as well? i.e Can Python access my webcam and stream it over the internet?

Comment: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/fmspy/0.1.0 may suit your needs, it appears to be an attempt to do just that.